# Run Visual Studio installer from Linux

Tags: linux, installation, visual-studio

I know Visual Studio offline installer can be made in Windows using the following command

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout
```

I want to know if it is possible to make an offline installation package of Visual Studio in Linux?

Comment: Visual Studio, doesn’t support Linux, Visual Studio Code does support it. The executable you describe in your question is a Windows executable and this cannot run on Linux